# SVG clipPath and transformations

Tags: svg

I have two nearly identical pieces of code where the right half of a circle should be clipped according to a rectangle. In the first example, all works well:

```
<svg>
    <clipPath id="cut">
        <rect width="100" height="100" x="100" y="50"></rect>
    </clipPath>

    <circle class="consumption" cx="100" cy="100" clip-path="url(#cut)" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8S3k/)

In the second one though, when I am using a translation on the circle to specify its position, nothing is shown anymore.

```
<svg>
    <clipPath id="cut">
        <rect width="100" height="100" x="100" y="50"></rect>
    </clipPath>

    <circle class="consumption" transform="translate(100,100)" clip-path="url(#cut)" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fA9y4/2/)

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the transform applies to the clipPath too.

From the [SVG specification...](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath)

> If clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse", the contents of the ‘clipPath’ represent values in the **current user coordinate system in place at the time when the ‘clipPath’ element is referenced** (i.e., the user coordinate system for the element referencing the ‘clipPath’ element via the ‘clip-path’ property).
>   If attribute ‘clipPathUnits’ is not specified, then the effect is as if a value of 'userSpaceOnUse' were specified.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to specify the x- and y-position of the `rect` relative to the translated position of the `circle`: http://jsfiddle.net/fA9y4/4/

Comment: But what about clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"? It seems to make Chrome and Firefox just ignore the clipPath...

Comment: @Tincho if you've another question, feel free to [ask it separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), ideally with an example.

Answer (score 11):

You can still use a "g" tag like that to make it work.

```
<g clip-path="url(#cut)">
 <circle class="consumption" transform="translate(100,100)" r="50"></circle>
</g>
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: This solution saves my day.

Comment: Note, not related to OP, but if the element already has any transformation that is meant to be applied *after* the clip-path, that will need to be extracted to the `g` tag as well.