# Individual symbols are clipped in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am basically trying to clip a chart containing "path" elements representing data points.
It seems like, path elements are not initially "transformed" and remain at (0,0) and are thus clipped by rectangle surrounding entire chart.

Basically, I have replaced "circle" elements as drawn in [D3 Brush Example](http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/7612013) with "path" elements of symbol type "circle".

```
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "point")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
.attr("r", function(d){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1) + 5);})
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.index); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
```

replaced with

```
.append("path")
.attr("class", "point")
.attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("circle"))
```

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxuozxj/23/). As you can see, only lower right quarter of the circle is visible and rest have been clipped out. What is going on? What is the solution?

**Edit:**
Also, the actual "clipping" is not working for those circles(paths). Why is that? Why does it work for "circle" but not for "path"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388689/svg-clippath-and-transformations

Comment: Please disable animations when you want people to debug your fiddles. every time I click on the canvas all points move towards the y-axis. This makes using the inspector impossible.

Also you might want to add your points/circles to a group element (<g>) for easier handling.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I tried with: svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
     .attr("clipPathUnits","objectBoundingBox")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);     But that rect (100x100) is not used as clipping path, I think entire svg is the clipping path. How to define dimensions of clipping path after setting clipPathUnits?

Comment: I think the way to go here is to translate the clipping path as well. That will of course require you to have one clipping path per point.

Comment: Isn't there any alternative? May be somehow limit size of the parent element on which data elements are drawn? Plus, if I were to have individual clipping paths for all data points, wouldn't all those clipping paths be identical as in (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How about making opacity 0 whenever symbols get outside the chart? Would that be a good solution?

Comment: Well, whatever works for you :) The easiest would probably be to put the clip path on a `g` element that contains all the symbols.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff So, first svg then g then all the shapes right? But how would I define clipping path's bounds for 'g' element? I mean svg would be bigger than 'g'. 'g' should define clipping area for symbols.

Comment: Ok got it. 1. Append clip path 2. Append rect defining clipping bounds 3. Append "g" element and assign clip url 4. Append data points to "g" element